# how is a function call on it's own considered a function call expression?

Tags: javascript

This makes sense to me as a function call expression: `let calculation = calculate()` because it's something equal to something.

But how is `calculate()` on its own a function call expression? A tutorial i'm watching basically said that the parenthesis at the end are what make it an expression, which I'm a little confused about.

Does it have to do with the parameters?

Comment: An expression can be evaluated, it doesn't matter if you store the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `let calculation = calculate()` it will assign `response` from `calculate()` to `calculation`, while in `calculate()` it will not assign `response` to any object.

> the parenthesis at the end are what make it an expression

To explain above line let's say you are not using `parenthesis` and simply using `let calc = calculate;` then it will assign `reference` of `calculate` to `calc`. And then it will call `calculate()` when you write `calc()`.

Try it below.

```js
function calculate() {
  return 1;
}

let calculation = calculate();
console.log('calculation');
console.log(calculation);

let calc = calculate;
console.log('calc');
console.log(calc);
console.log('calc()');
console.log(calc());
```